# List ul items are behaving weird

Tags: html, css

I am doing a header navbar and a have a bigger font-size at the item floating left than the others floating right. The problem as you might see in the coderun is that the items with smaller font-size ain't v-aligned the same the one with the bigger font-size

I have tried for hours but with no luck, what might be the problem?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: black;
}

header ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

#logo a {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
}

.navitem {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <ul>
                <li id="logo"><a id="first" href="#">Relax</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

Comment: you need to avoid float if you want to do this .. keep them inline-block

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem. I won't bother with a real answer, but setting line-height on the logo to 100% seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/50obLr4z/

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a nav like this can be a little clunky as you need to have them in reverse order in your HTML, then use the float to reverse how they're rendered (try making the text in each unique to see what I mean).

Something a little more semantic, and using Flexbox would be:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: black;
}

header ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#logo a {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <ul>
                <li id="logo"><a id="first" href="#">Relax</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing 1</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing 2 </a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing 3</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing 4</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Testing 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly my teacher won't allow us to use either flexbox or grid since he thinks that it is not supportive enough, could there be another solution?

Comment: Ya, get a new teacher, or show him this... 
91.95% global browser usage supports flexbox unprefixed https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and 85.36% global browser usage supports grid 
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

There's always another solution when it comes to HTML/CSS, it's just comes down to what's best for your particular needs. What I would recommend is taking a look at the Bootstrap 3 navbar. It's solves the issue you have, without using flexbox or grid.

Comment: yeah i did show him can i use but didn't help. Thanks for the advice, will check it out